# onNavigationItemSelected not working in NavigationView

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-navigationview

Please can someone help me with fragments from the navigation drawer, for some reason I can't get them to work and all the code looks right.

[Here](https://github.com/Matt-Hutchings/The-Midlands-Meander) is the link to the source code.

Comment: Please explain the problem you are having. Saying "not working" is too broad.

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: If you download and open up the android project you'll notice that its has a navigation drawer which I'd like to use properly, so for example I'd like to click on **The Wetlands** which in turn should change the current fragment to the **fragment_the_wetlands** 
I've just got a dummy clock there for now to see whether or not the fragment is changing.
I can't seem to get this right please help with that.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Have a look at your `MainActivity.java`.

You have implemented the callbacks for `NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener` in `MainActivity` as below,

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
    // blah blah
}
```

Also check the `setupDrawerContent` method.

```
private void setupDrawerContent(NavigationView navigationView) {
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(
            new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                    menuItem.setChecked(true);
                    drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                    return true;
                }
            });
}
```

In this method you are creating a local `OnNavigationItemSelectedListener`.

So you are not using the `OnNavigationItemSelectedListener` that you have overridden in `MainActivity`.

The solution is to use `this` as argument for `setNavigationItemSelectedListener`. By doing this all your clicks will go the `onNavigationItemSelected` of `MainActivity` rather than going to the local `onNavigationItemSelected`.

```
private void setupDrawerContent(NavigationView navigationView) {
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}
```

Also move the code in the local `onNavigationItemSelected` to the `onNavigationItemSelected` of `MainActivity`.

So your `onNavigationItemSelected` will be something like this,

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = menuItem.getItemId();
    menuItem.setChecked(true);
    drawerLayout.closeDrawers();

    if (id == R.id.nav_home) {
        // Handle the home action
        Toast.makeText(this, "Home", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_the_wetlands) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "The Wetlands", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        TheWetlandsFragment theWetlandsFragment = new TheWetlandsFragment();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.relativelayout_for_fragment, theWetlandsFragment, theWetlandsFragment.getTag()).commit();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_the_mistbelt_forests) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "The Mistbelt Forests", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

Also change your `activity_main_drawer_view.xml` as follows to solve the multiple selection issue you have in the Navigation Drawer,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_home"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_dashboard"
            android:title="Home" />
    </group>

    <item android:title="Information">
        <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_the_wetlands"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_event"
                android:title="The Wetlands" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_the_mistbelt_forests"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_event"
                android:title="The Mistbelt Forests" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_the_grasslands"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_event"
                android:title="The Grasslands" />
        </group>
    </item>

    <item android:title="Quick Go To">
        <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_accommodation"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_event"
                android:title="Accommodation" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_cuisine"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_forum"
                android:title="Cuisine" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_leisure_activites"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_forum"
                android:title="Leisure &amp; Activites" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_agri_tourism"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_forum"
                android:title="Agri-tourism" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_education"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_forum"
                android:title="Education" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_arts_crafts_decor"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_forum"
                android:title="Arts, Crafts &amp; DeCor" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_selective_shopping"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_forum"
                android:title="Selective Shopping" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_for_children"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_forum"
                android:title="For Children" />
        </group>
    </item>

    <item android:title="Midlands Animals">
        <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_midlands_birding_checklist"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_dashboard"
                android:title="Midlands Birding Checklist" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_midlands_mammals_checklist"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_dashboard"
                android:title="Midlands Mammals Checklist" />
        </group>
    </item>

</menu>
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 39):

Use this code:

```
navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigationView); 
navigationView.bringToFront();
```

Comment: This helped me... thannks a lot !!

Comment: Wow, I just do not understand why this worked...but it worked.

Comment: With databinding `.bringToFront()`  solved the issue. So:
`_binding.navView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)` - not enough.
Then add `_binding.navView.bringToFront()` - and the listener is triggered.

Comment: Thank you, 4 days without solution and the answer was here:  navigationView.bringToFront();
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 7):

Don't use

```
NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
```

instead of it do this

```
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: This Answer is truly a life saver

Comment: For those following [this official tutorial](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#add_a_navigation_drawer), this is the solution you want.

Answer (score 6):

I have also faced the same problem some time back, and at the end i realized that i have not wrote the 2nd line of the following code

```
navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);        
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
```

you make sure you have written the same otherwise your listener will not work

Answer (score 1):

in my case i forgot to initialize navigation menu.

kindly follow following code:

```
public void initSideMenu() {

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}
```

happy coding...

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have implement the interface NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener.
Second point make sure to add these lines otherwise listnere will not be called.

```
navigationView=(NavigationView) findviewbyid(R.id.navigation_view);
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Add this line**
navigationView.bringToFront();
Its works for me

Answer (score 0):

This solved the issue for me->

Before, the NavigationView element was above the other elements

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:nextFocusRight="@+id/recyclerview"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"

        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            app:elevation="0dp"
            android:nextFocusLeft="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:touchscreenBlocksFocus="false"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"/>

    </FrameLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/drawer_color"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:menu="@menu/nav_menu"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/white"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/white"/>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        ...
    </ScrollView>
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

After I move the NavigationView to the bottom, the issue was solved :)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:nextFocusRight="@+id/recyclerview"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        ...
    </ScrollView>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"

        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            app:elevation="0dp"
            android:nextFocusLeft="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:touchscreenBlocksFocus="false"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"/>

    </FrameLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/drawer_color"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:menu="@menu/nav_menu"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/white"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/white"/>
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```