# Navigation item click event doesn’t work in Android

Tags: android

Navigationview click event doesn’t work in Android. I click to item-element but the codes doesn’t work. The Java and XML Codes are in below.

Codes:

```
        menulayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawerlayout);
        navview = (NavigationView)findViewById(R.id.navview);

        navview.setNavigationItemSelectedListener( new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener () {
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem secilen){

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "tıklandı" + secilen, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                if(secilen.getItemId() == R.id.profilitem){

                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), profil.class));

                }else if(secilen.getItemId() == R.id.haberitem){

                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), haber.class));

                }else if(secilen.getItemId() == R.id.cashgonderitem){

                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), cashgonder.class));

                }else if(secilen.getItemId() == R.id.cashalitem){

                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), cashal.class));

                }else if(secilen.getItemId() == R.id.ayaritem){

                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ayar.class));

                }else if(secilen.getItemId() == R.id.yardimitem){

                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), yardim.class));

                }

                return false;

            }
        });
```

XML Code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/drawerlayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".navdraweroyun"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
>

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
    >

        <include
            layout="@layout/activity_oyunbar"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/navview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            app:menu="@menu/navmenu"
    />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I hope I haven't a error in XML.

How I can resolve this problem?

I hope you are understand. I doesn't have a good English.

I need your help.

Comment: can you re-format this code, it's not readable in current state. Also add more information about what are you trying to do and what you are using

Comment: @Daniel I edited the question and the code. I would go a another activity when click item in navigationview

Comment: take a look https://stackoverflow.com/a/49483633/8103819, maybe this will solve your problem

Comment: @Daniel I added XML Code in question. I hope I haven't error in XML

Comment: Your layout looks OK. What exactly does happen when you click? Do you see the `Toast`? Does the drawer close automatically?

Comment: @Mike M. Not my drawer doesn’t close and I doesn’t her Toast message.

Comment: Hmm. Is that `<DrawerLayout>` ending up inside some other layout? Or is it the `Activity`'s content `View`?

Comment: @Mike M.Not problem in Drawerlayout. View?

Comment: Where do you use that layout?

Comment: @Mike M. Excuse me I doesn’t understand

Comment: Where in your code do you use `R.layout.the_layout_you_posted`?

Comment: @Mike M. I use startactivity.

Comment: Well, your description doesn't really match up with what I can gather from the posted code. Please put together a [mcve].