# Getting same value in click event button in for Android

Tags: android, loops, for-loop, button

I have a for loop in Android. I create Buttons and button click events in loop. The codes are in below.

The codes:

```
for(ii = 0; ii < yardimarray.size(); ii++){

            Button yardimmtv = new Button(yardim.this);
            yardimmtv.setText(yardimarray.get(ii));
            yardimmtv.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            yardimmtv.setTextSize(17);
            yardimmtv.setLayoutParams(yardimtvlp);
            yardimmtv.setBackgroundResource(tvalue.resourceId);
            yardiml.addView(yardimmtv);

            iii = ii + 1;

            yardimmtv.setOnClickListener ( new View.OnClickListener () {
                public void onClick (View yardimmv){

                    Intent yardimbgecis = new Intent(yardim.this, yardimbilgi.class);
                    yardimbgecis.putExtra("yardimid", String.valueOf(iii));
                    finish();
                    startActivity(yardimbgecis);

                }
            });

        }
```

But yardimid is always 9 and loop run 9 times.

How I can resolve this problem?

I need your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting on yout Button, the position as a TAG. Something like `yardimmtv.setTag(ii);` And then onClick you get the tag of the button clicked using `v.getTag()` and put in Extras

Comment: Thanks. The problem was resolved. I added tag to button. and put on extras with onclick view gettag.

Comment: Please look my other question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57698725/navigation-item-click-event-doesn-t-work-in-android